# Persisting Apache NiFi Templates in Kubernetes with Persistent Volumes

Tags: kubernetes, apache-nifi

I'm facing an issue with Apache NiFi in a Kubernetes environment where, even though I've mounted a volume to the directory where NiFi templates are stored, the templates are not visible after pod startup.

Are there specific NiFi configuration settings or best practices that I should follow to achieve this persistence?

Below the Nifi StatefulSet that I have deployed in my cluster

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: nifi
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nifi
  serviceName: "nifi"
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nifi
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nifi
          image: apache/nifi:1.22.0
          securityContext:
            runAsUser: 0
            runAsGroup: 0
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: nifi-configmap
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /path/to/file/
              name: nifi-data
            - name: nifi-database
              mountPath: "/opt/nifi/nifi-current/database_repository"
            - name: nifi-flowfile
              mountPath: "/opt/nifi/nifi-current/flowfile_repository"
            - name: nifi-content
              mountPath: "/opt/nifi/nifi-current/content_repository"
            - name: nifi-provenance
              mountPath: "/opt/nifi/nifi-current/provenance_repository"
            - name: nifi-state
              mountPath: "/opt/nifi/nifi-current/state"
            - name: nifi-conf
              mountPath: "/opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf"
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: nifi-data 
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      storageClassName: "standard"
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi
  - metadata:
      name: nifi-flowfile
    spec:
      storageClassName: "standard"
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi
  - metadata:
      name: nifi-content
    spec:
      storageClassName: "standard"
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi
  - metadata:
      name: nifi-provenance
    spec:
      storageClassName: "standard"
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi
  - metadata:
      name: nifi-state
    spec:
      storageClassName: "standard"
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi
  - metadata:
      name: nifi-conf
    spec:
      storageClassName: "standard"
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi
  - metadata:
      name: nifi-database
    spec:
      storageClassName: "standard"
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi
  - metadata:
      name: nifi-conf-pvc
    spec:
      storageClassName: "standard"
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi
```

I truly appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your YAML configuration, you've mounted various NiFi directories to persistent volume claims, but you haven't explicitly indicated where NiFi templates are stored.

Mount a volume to the directory where NiFi stores its templates. This is generally `/opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/templates` for a standard NiFi Docker image.

Update your volumeMounts like this:

```
- name: nifi-conf
  mountPath: "/opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf"
```

Since you are running the container as root (`runAsUser: 0`), ensure that the mounted directory has appropriate permissions. Otherwise, NiFi may not be able to read or write to this directory.

Ensure that the NiFi properties file (`nifi.properties`) in your ConfigMap has settings that align with your volume mounts. For example, check the path for `nifi.templates.directory`.

If you are pre-populating the volume with templates, make sure that they are readable by the NiFi process.